# Any newbie friendly & up-to-date Node tutorials and resources?

Tags: node.js

I've been browsing stackoverflow looking for some tutorials that are newbie friendly but I can't find anything I am able to follow.

I've been referred to pedro texeira's mongoose screen cast which I am not able to follow at all because he doesn't start at the beginning (where he actually creates the app and creates the files, etc.).

I've also been referred to [this](http://www.wonderlandlabs.com/wll_drupal/node/mongoose/index.html), which also is impossible for a beginner to follow seeing that I have no idea in which files the codes that are being provided need to go.

The thing is, I'm really eager to learn Node but I'm finding it incredibly hard to find tutorials that I'm actually able to follow and get the application up and running.

So far the only node resources I've been able to follow are:

- howtonode.org
- nodebeginner.org

I'd love to have a big list of websites/blogs that are being updated constantly with some tutorials to follow so I can get a hang of the platform.

Answer (score 1):

There is this http://nodeguide.com/

This one is really good too, from just reading the preview. But not free
http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449398583/

Comment: Thanks! I'm really looking forward to Guillaume Rauch's book that's being released on May 1st ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found [Mixu's Node Book](http://book.mixu.net/) to be informative.